# local package installation issue with pkg.installed function

Tags: salt-stack

I want to install a local package with the following SaltStack code:

```
test_package:
    pkg.installed:
        - source: /suresh/depot/files/tss-7.0.1.x86_64.rpm
        - target: /product/install
        - cwd: /suresh/product
        - user: root
        - group: root
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error: `.rpm package is present /suresh/depot/files folder.`

```
      ID: test_package
Function: pkg.installed
    Name: tss-7.0.1.x86_64.rpm
  Result: False
 Comment: Error occurred installing package(s). Additional info follows:

          errors:
              - Running scope as unit run-9356.scope.
                Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
                Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
                 * base: ftp.heanet.ie
                 * extras: ftp.heanet.ie
                 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
                No package tss-7.0.1.x86_64.rpm available.
                Error: Nothing to do
 Started: 12:12:19.575701
Duration: 5584.961 ms
```

Comment: test_package:
  pkg.installed:
    - source: /suresh/depot/files/tss-7.0.1.x86_64.rpm
    - target: /suresh/install
    - cwd: /suresh/product/
    - user: root
    - group: root

Answer (score 0):

Your source location should be inside the salt folder.

Example: 
  If you are saved salt file on `/usr/local/etc/salt/states`
  and if your file inside this folder, say  `/usr/local/etc/salt/states/pkgs/files/tss-7.0.1.x86_64.rpm` Then

```
test_package:
    pkg.installed:
        - source: salt://pkgs/tss-7.0.1.x86_64.rpm
        - user: root
        - group: root
```